# Button to control both form and subform

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a form(`Salefrm`) and within that form there is a subform (`Salefrm_subform`).For now my `Add` command button will work only for the main form `Salefrm` , how can i make it work with `Salefrm_subform` as well.

Here is what happen when i click on Add .Do i need to have some code in Add to control the subform

[image]

Comment: Is your SubForm not set to `Addition`?

Comment: @PaulFrancis what you mean ?...first time using access for form here, was using vb.net till now so pardon my ignorance

Comment: You should be able to add records on SubForm without the need of any complication. Can you take a snap shot of your form set up and edit your post?

Comment: @PaulFrancis picture added

Comment: Upon creation of a parent record you will be able to create a child record.